# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\PMSS\login.php on line 95

Tags: php

This is my Login.php

```
<?php

//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Please fill in the login details!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $query = "SELECT  email, password, position FROM user   WHERE   email = :email ";

    $query_params = array(':email' => $_POST['username'],);

    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
    //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

    //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));

    }

    //This will be the variable to determine whether or not the user's information is correct.
    //we initialize it as false.
    $validated_info = false;
    $login_ok = false;

    //fetching all the rows from the query
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if ($row) {
        //if we encrypted the password, we would unencrypt it here, but in our case we just
        //compare the two passwords
        if ($_POST['password'] === $row['password']) {
            $login_ok = true;       
        }

    // If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
    // Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again 
        if ($login_ok) {
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Login Successful!";
            $response["posts"]   = array();

                foreach ($row as $rerow) {
                $row = array(
                $post["position"] = $rerow["position"]
                            );

                array_push($response["posts"], $post);
                }

                die(json_encode($response));
        } 
        else {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!";
            die(json_encode($response));
        }

    } 
}   
else {
    ?>
    <h1>Login</h1> 
    <form action="login.php" method="post"> 
        Username:<br /> 
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /> 
        <br /><br /> 
        Password:<br /> 
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" /> 
        <br /><br /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
    </form> 
    <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    <?php
}
?>
```

I not sure which place I didn't put close bracket. Can you all help me check out see? I not sure where to put the close bracket. Is is anything to do with my condition while retrieving my data to my android? If it is, please state it out as for me to know the syntax I write was correct or not.

Comment: And this is why indenting your code is very, very useful.

Comment: It's worth learning how to indent code properly so that you can tell.  Without having any indication of the nesting logic (I.E. the indentation), it's near impossible for an outsider to work out what you intended.

Comment: Where do you close your `if (!empty($_POST)) {`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a missing bracket.

Comment: because I use notepad to do it.. It does not have the indent function, and I need to space every line of code.

Comment: @Nick: don't write code in Notepad. Get a real editor.

Comment: @Nick: Notepad is not a code editor.  I *highly* suggest using a "real" code editor.  I personally like http://www.geany.org/.  Or you can also look at http://notepad-plus-plus.org/  Trying to code in an editor that doesn't understand code isn't a good idea.

Comment: I does think of using notepad-plus instead of notepad. Some of my classmate they suggest me use Adobe Dreamweaver..

Comment: @Nick "It does not have the indent function", four spaces is an indent.

Comment: @RocketHazmat due to my asking question bad feedback, now I can't post question and can't even comment on other people's question

Comment: @Nick: Why are you telling me this?

Comment: @Nick I'm afraid that is what happens when you consistently use SO as a debugging service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is missing the **}** for `if (!empty($_POST)) {`

```
    if (!empty($_POST)) {


     //code...

    } else {
    ?>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <form action="login.php" method="post">
          Username:<br />
          <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
          <br /><br />
           Password:<br />
           <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" />
           <br /><br />
           <input type="submit" value="Login" />
       </form>
      <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    <?php
    }
} // <---- this is missing
```

Answer (score 0):

If I may, I'd like to tell you that your code is kinda messy. Indentation saves your life, remmeber.

---

Anyway I've seen that no errors is found if you remove the **fifth** line of your code:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
```

This is not closed. `if ($row) {` is closed just before the `else` that is above the login heading title. As matter of fact, if the DB doesn't return any result, it shows the login page.

Anyway the **fifth** line is unecessary since just below it you do the control on specific vars. You don't have to check the full `$_POST` array.

Comment: I need use the `if (!empty($_POST)) {` in the matter of fact I will transfer my android data to php script,the form actually is not needed

Comment: @Nick: Allright. Then... close it!